# HTML agility parsing error

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Sample Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="demo_form.asp" id="form1" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();    
doc.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\sample.html"));
HtmlNode nd = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@id='form1']");
//nd.InnerHtml is "".
//nd.InnerText is "".
```

Problem

```
nd.ChildNodes //Collection(to get all nodes in form) is always null.
nd.SelectNodes("/input") //returns null.
nd.SelectNodes("./input") //returns null.
"//form[@id='form1']/input" //returns null.
```

what i want is to access childnodes of form tag with id=form1 one by one in order of occurrence. I tried same xpath in chrome developer console and it works just exactly the way i wanted. Is HTMlAgility pack is having problem in reading html from file or Web.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want all childnodes of Forms tag in a htmlNodecollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following statement before loading the document:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
```

HtmlAgilityPack's default behaviour adds all the form's inner-elements as siblings in stead of children. The statement above alters that behaviour so that they (meaning the input tags) will appear as childnodes.

Your code would look like this:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();    
doc.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\sample.html"));
HtmlNode nd = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@id='form1']");
etc...
```

references:

1. bug issue & fix: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/23074
2. codeplex forum post: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/247206

Comment: :D ha ha thank you. that worked. I guess i have update my htmlagility dll periodically.

Comment: nuget ftw ;) -> and yes it's only there since v 1.4.5, current version is 1.4.6. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid and may be preventing the html agility pack from working properly.

Try adding a doctype (and an xml namespace) to the start of your document and change your input element's closing tags from > to />

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sample Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="demo_form.asp" id="form1" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
Verified with http://validator.w3.org/check : Passed. But getting same error. :(